# Diagrams in category theory

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone help me please? I'm wondering how to draw this diagram with LaTeX.
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Such things can be drawn very conveniently with `tikz-cd`.

Comment: Try `\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}  
A \arrow[r,"b"] \arrow[d,"g"] & C \arrow[r,"\alpha"] \arrow[d,"\beta"]& D \arrow[d,"\gamma"]\\
B \arrow[rru,"h"] & B' \arrow[r,"\omega"] & D'
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}`

Comment: @marmot You're flash. I lost many times with Captcha. :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano Slow marmots get caught by the eagles.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can easily draw your diagrams with the free online tool [tikzcd-editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/).

Screenshot:

[image]

Generated Code by clicking the `{}` button (not an MWE):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[d, "g"] \arrow[r, "f"] & B \arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "\gamma"] & D \arrow[d, "\beta"] \\
C \arrow[rru, "h"] & B' \arrow[r, "\lambda"] & D'
\end{tikzcd}
```

[Link to live example](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#eyJub2RlcyI6W3sicG9zaXRpb24iOlswLDBdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkEifSx7InBvc2l0aW9uIjpbMSwwXSwidmFsdWUiOiJCIn0seyJwb3NpdGlvbiI6WzIsMF0sInZhbHVlIjoiRCJ9LHsicG9zaXRpb24iOlswLDFdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkMifSx7InBvc2l0aW9uIjpbMSwxXSwidmFsdWUiOiJCJyJ9LHsicG9zaXRpb24iOlsyLDFdLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkQnIn1dLCJlZGdlcyI6W3siZnJvbSI6MCwidG8iOjMsInZhbHVlIjoiZyJ9LHsiZnJvbSI6MCwidG8iOjEsInZhbHVlIjoiZiJ9LHsiZnJvbSI6MSwidG8iOjIsInZhbHVlIjoiXFxhbHBoYSJ9LHsiZnJvbSI6MSwidG8iOjQsInZhbHVlIjoiXFxnYW1tYSJ9LHsiZnJvbSI6MiwidG8iOjUsInZhbHVlIjoiXFxiZXRhIn0seyJmcm9tIjo0LCJ0byI6NSwidmFsdWUiOiJcXGxhbWJkYSJ9LHsiZnJvbSI6MywidG8iOjIsInZhbHVlIjoiaCJ9XX0=)

Comment: Certainly a very nice tool, where can you find the instructions for use?

Comment: Is it possible to remove the grid in the editor you linked above to take a screenshot?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor Yes, remove or comment out the line containing `border: 2px dashed #ccc;` in the `.grid-cell` class in [`master.css`](https://github.com/yishn/tikzcd-editor/blob/3f0b2eb64048b8898ec49811bbf16d7176d52292/css/master.css#L85).

Answer (score 13):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}  
A \arrow[r,"b"] \arrow[d,"g"] & C \arrow[r,"\alpha"] \arrow[d,"\gamma",pos=0.4,swap]& D \arrow[d,"\beta"]\\
B \arrow[rru,"h",pos=0.7,swap] & B' \arrow[r,"\omega"] & D'
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I added the proposal to prove that users are willing to help. However, the purpose of this site is not to get screen shots converted to LaTeX code. Rather, the idea is that you try something, and if you get stuck, you have a code that you can show and others will help you solve that problem.

Answer (score 10):

My code is only "basic".

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r, "f"] \arrow[d, "g"'] & B \arrow[r, "\alpha"] \arrow[d, "h"'] & D \arrow[d, "\beta"] \\
C \arrow[rru, "\gamma"'] & B' \arrow[r, "\lambda"'] & D'
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is with `pstricks`– more precisely the `psmatrix` environment:

```
\documentclass[border=8pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

 $ \begin{psmatrix}[colsep =1.2cm, rowsep=1.2cm, nodesepA=2pt, nodesepB=1pt, shortput=nab, labelsep=1pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12, linewidth=0.6pt]
A & B & D \\
C & B' & D'
%% horizontal maps
\ncline{1,1}{1,2}^{b}
\ncline{1,2}{1,3}^{\alpha}
\ncline{2,2}{2,3}_{\lambda}
%% oblique map
\ncline{2,1}{1,3}\naput[npos=0.7]{h}
%% vertical maps
\ncline{1,1}{2,1}<{g}
\ncline[border=1pt]{1,2}{2,2}\nbput[npos=0.35]{\gamma}
\ncline{1,3}{2,3} >{\beta}
\end{psmatrix} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ! Package auto-pst-pdf Error: 
    "shell escape" (or "write18") is not enabled:
    auto-pst-pdf will not work!, use -shell-escape  to resove